# json_decode() single quote

Tags: php, json

I want to use `json_decode()` to decode a string stored in a database like this:

```
{"results":[{"r":"1","c":"0"},{"r":"2","c":"0"},{"r":"3","c":"0"}]}
```

The problem is: the function returns `NULL`.

But when I try the following code, everything works:

```
$data ='{"results":[{"r":"1","c":"0"},{"r":"2","c":"0"},{"r":"3","c":"0"}]}';
$JO=json_decode($data);
var_dump($JO);
```

The value returned from the database is exactly the same as I described above.

Comment: I assume `$tmpString[2]` is just a typo? Also show us the output of: `var_dump($yourData);` to check the length of the string and if there are any hidden characters in there

Comment: I do not get `null` when substituting `$data` for `$tmpString[2]`

Comment: Where is it? $tmpString[2])

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks, fixed it, it was the data i got from database.

Comment: do a `var_dump()` on the data you get from the db. make sure it's what you think it should be. `null` is returned either if the input data is a javascript null, or the decoding failed, in which case you have to check `json_last_error()` for the reason why.

Comment: @devpro it was a typo my bad sorry

Comment: @MarcB var_dump() returns: string(167) "{ "results": [{ "r": "1", "c": "0" }, { "r": "2", "c": "0" }, { "r": "3", "c": "0" }] }"

Comment: @Mehrdad Your string is only 87 characters long, so you must got some hidden characters in there which make your json invalid. Try to use `trim()` on the json data

Comment: What rcu getting in var_dump($JO);

Comment: @Rizier123 still got the problem...

Comment: @devpro that line returns NULL

Comment: @Mehrdad As Marc B already mention then just check `json_last_error()` and tell us what you get.

Comment: @Rizier123 it returns 4

Comment: This means you got a syntax error in your json. But your json which you show us is valid. If you do: `var_dump(trim($yourJSON));` is the length still 167 or 87?

Comment: @Rizier123 I changed the database and copied exactly the same string, but the var_dump(trim($yourJSON)); returns 67 for $data and 120 the data from database!

Comment: @Mehrdad But `json_decode(trim($yourJSON))` doesn't work?

Comment: @Rizier123 I think I found the problem, I'm working on it, reading from database I guess I add some text to it to show it as html, and it is the reason.

Comment: @Rizier123 yes the problem was that, I added extra strings to it for html, thanks man you saved my eyes...I was looking for the problem for more than a day.

Answer (score 0):

For all the people who might get the same problem, my problem was that when I was getting data from database to display it, I was adding html style and table parameters to the data, after removing them everything went back to normal.